# I cannot detect where is ^M in my .gvimrc

Tags: gvim, macvim

I have the following `.gvimrc`:

```
vim9script

# -----------------------------------
# This file is sourced AFTER .vimrc
# -----------------------------------
set mousehide

# Set fonts for gvim
# fontsize = 11 with the 14'' MacBook you have exactly two columns
# with textwidth = 78
var fontsize = 18
var fontface = "Arial"
var fontsize_tail = ""

if has("gui_win32")
     fontsize = 14
     fontface = "FiraCode_NFM:h"
     fontsize_tail = ":cANSI:qDRAFT"
     set guioptions-=T
    # Open gvim in full-screen
    au GUIEnter * simalt ~x
elseif has("gui_macvim")
     fontsize_tail = ""
     fontface = "Fira\ Code:h"
endif

&guifont = fontface .. string(fontsize) .. fontsize_tail

def ChangeFontsize(n: number)
    var old_redraw = &lazyredraw
    set lazyredraw

    fontsize = fontsize + n
    &guifont = fontface .. string(fontsize) .. fontsize_tail

    &lazyredraw = old_redraw
enddef

# Some commands
command! FontsizeIncrease :vim9cmd ChangeFontsize(1)<cr>
command! FontsizeDecrease :vim9cmd ChangeFontsize(-1)<cr>
```

However, when I call `:FontsizeIncrease` of `:FontsizeDecrease` I have a `E488: Trailing character ^M` but I cannoty figure out where such an `^M` is.
I tried to `:!dos2unix ~/.gvimrc` but with no success. I am working on MacOs Sonoma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating user commands with `command`, the trailing enter is somewhat implicit. You do not need to add `<cr>`. The leading colon is also implicit and not needed.

This is all in contrast to mappings.

Comment: Ah correct! These things are really difficult to remember.